# Ruby on Rails: Many-to-Many Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

New to rails. I'm creating a project with several database tables all in relation to each other. I would like to know how to add a foreign key reference to an instance after it has been created. Code below:

In schema:

```
    class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :posts
      has_many :owners
      has_many :users, through: :owners
    end

    class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :blog
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :messages
       has_many :posts
       has_many :owners
       has_many :blogs, through: :owners
    end
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages
   has_many :posts
   has_many :owners
   has_many :blogs, through: :owners
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :blog
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :owners
  has_many :users, through: :owners
end
```

In rails console:

```
blog1 = Blog.first
user1 = User.first
blog1.users = user1
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<User:0x0000000487e9f8>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make it so that user1 becomes the owner of the blog, you could try

```
blog1 = Blog.first 
user1 = User.first 
Owner.create(user: user1, blog: blog1)
```

or

```
Owner.create(user: User.first, blog:Blog.first)
```

Hope I answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

Since a Blog `has many` Users, `.users` will be a collection (Array or ActiveRecord_Relation).

Try: `blog1.users << user1`

[<< (shovel operator) docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `blog1.users`, you are getting back an array, so doing `= something` wouldn't work. While you can just add to the array using `<<`  or say `array.push()`, it's not the best practice.

Instead, has_many (or has_one, etc), allows you to use `build_` notation to create related objects. So you could do: `blog1.users.build`, which will create a new user referenced for the blog. Or if you want to persist it, you can call `.users.create`

There are many ways to go around it, but using `ActiveRecord` methods if available is a nice way to keep code readable and short.